# List comprehension and function returning multiple values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I wanted to use list comprehension to avoid writing a for loop appending to some lists. But can it work with a function that returns multiple values? I expected this (simplified example) code to work...

```
def calc(i):
    a = i * 2
    b = i ** 2
    return a, b

steps = [1,2,3,4,5]

ay, be = [calc(s) for s in steps]
```

... but it doesn't :(

The for-loop appending to each list works:

```
def calc(i):
    a = i * 2
    b = i ** 2
    return a, b

steps = [1,2,3,4,5]

ay, be = [],[]

for s in steps:
    a, b = calc(s)
    ay.append(a)
    be.append(b)
```

Is there a better way or do I just stick with this?

Comment: The *reason* it doesn't work is that your list comprehension gives you a *single* list with 2-tuples in it. The unpacking to two variables will work if there are exactly 2 items in the list, but those variables' values will be 2-tuples. What you want is a 2-item list containing two separate lists, which you can get using `zip()` as shown by hcwhasa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `zip` with `*`:

```
>>> ay, by = zip(*(calc(x) for x in steps))
>>> ay
(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
>>> by
(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
```

Comment: Well, that was easy! Thanks. Guess I need to read up again on zip() and find out what that star is doing...

Comment: For anyone else reading this in the future: the explanation (I think) is that the function returns multiple values in the form [(1), (2), (etc)] and zip(*) means unzip.

Answer (score 4):

The horrendous "space efficient" version that returns iterators:

```
from itertools import tee

ay, by = [(r[i] for r in results) for i, results in enumerate(tee(map(calc, steps), 2))]
```

But basically just use `zip` because most of the time it's not worth the ugly.

---

Explanation:

```
zip(*(calc(x) for x in steps))
```

will do `(calc(x) for x in steps)` to get an *iterator* of `[(2, 1), (4, 4), (6, 9), (8, 16), (10, 25)]`.

When you unpack, you do the equivalent of

```
zip((2, 1), (4, 4), (6, 9), (8, 16), (10, 25))
```

so all of the items are stored in memory at once. Proof:

```
def return_args(*args):
    return args

return_args(*(calc(x) for x in steps))
#>>> ((2, 1), (4, 4), (6, 9), (8, 16), (10, 25))
```

Hence all items are in memory at once.

---

So how does mine work?

`map(calc, steps)` is the same as `(calc(x) for x in steps)` (Python 3). This is an iterator. On Python 2, use `imap` or `(calc(x) for x in steps)`.

`tee(..., 2)` gets two iterators that store the *difference* in iteration. If you iterate in lockstep the `tee` will take `O(1)` memory. If you do not, the `tee` can take up to `O(n)`. So now we have a usage that lets us have `O(1)` memory up to this point.

`enumerate` obviously will keep this in constant memory.

`(r[i] for r in results)` returns an iterator that takes the `i`<sup>th</sup> item from each of the results. This means it receives, in this case, a pair (so `r=(2,1)`, `r=(4,4)`, etc. in turn). It returns the specific iterator.

Hence if you iterate `ay` and `by` in lockstep constant memory will be used. The memory usage is proportional to the distance between the iterators. This is useful in many cases (imagine diffing a file or suchwhat) but as I said most of the time it's not worth the ugly. There's an extra constant-factor overhead, too.

Comment: `zip` is already as efficient as you can get, unless you're using `python 2`, which you really shouldn't be.

Comment: False. I'll add proof in a mo'.

Comment: This is annoying to read but does what it’s supposed to, so… :D

Comment: @simonzack Does this suffice as sufficient evidence?

Answer (score 2):

You should have shown us what

```
[calc(s) for s in xrange(5)]
```

does give you, i.e.

```
[(0, 0), (2, 1), (4, 4), (6, 9), (8, 16)]
```

While it isn't the 2 lists that you want, it is still a list of lists.  Further more, doesn't that look just like?

```
zip((0, 2, 4, 6, 8), (0, 1, 4, 9, 16))
```

`zip` repackages a set of lists.  Usually it is illustrated with 2 longer lists, but it works just as well many short lists.

The third step is to remember that `fn(*[arg1,arg2, ...]) = fn(arg1,arg2, ...)`, that is, the `*` unpacks a list.

Put it all together to get hcwhsa's answer.